# Multi-Sig "withdraw" function fails, suspect fallback handler?

Tags: gnosis-safe

We're encountering an issue calling a contract function from our Gnosis Safe wallet. The function is a very simple "withdraw" function thats meant to send ether to the caller like `Address.sendValue(payable(_msgSender()), address(this).balance);`. However this function throws an error despite other functions in the contract working fine with Gnosis Safe. We suspect the issue is related to the fallback handler, but aren't sure what specifically is the problem. Is this something other users have had trouble with in the past? Are we doing something wrong? Is there any change we can make to the fallback handler that might fix this issue? Thanks